# Get references to child components in ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a parent component (`ParentComponent`) and a child component (`ChildComponent`).

I want to build a QueryList of all of the children, so that I can set the `isOpen` property on some of them. The children are in an `*ngFor` and I cannot get any of `@ContentChildren`, `@ContentChild`, `@ViewChildren` or `@viewChild` to work -- they always come back as an empty array.

ParentComponent controller

```
import { Component, ContentChild, ContentChildren, OnInit, QueryList, ViewChild,  ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent, { descendants: true }) childrenRef: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
  children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  items = [1, 3, 4, 4, 5];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.info(this.childrenRef);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.children = this.childrenRef;
    console.info(this.childrenRef, this.childrenRef.length);
    console.info(this.children, this.children.length);
  }
}
```

ParentComponent template

```
<app-child *ngFor="let item of items"></app-child>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/atw-angular-select-child-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts

I suspect I am either approaching this completely wrongly or I am fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: is ViewChildren but you get it in the `ngAfterViewInit` not in ngAfterContentInit

Comment: Oh no! It's that simple. I feel a fool. Add that as an answer and I will tick it for you. Thank you :)